# My Window closes as soon I am executing with an error?

Tags: python, pygame

So that's my Code: I have tried it with Python 3.8,3.7.6 .
It opens the window and closes it immediately.
And in Addition it shows an Error :

> ```
> if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
> ```

```
import pygame

#initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            running = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is an enumerator constant and is not callable:
(see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module)

<s>`if event.type == pygame.QUIT():`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains error

> line 13, in 
> if event.type == pygame.QUIT(): TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Quit is not callable, it's attribute, do the following:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```